# Open Source .Net Object Database or Document Database for use in Hosted environment

Tags: c#, .net, object-oriented-database, document-database

I am looking at creating a web site and I want to try and learn either a Object Database or a Document Database.   I am going to be using a hosting provider so I won't be able to install any software.  I am unable to purchase any licensing so I need to be able use either a free or open source Object/Document Database.  Are there any free Object/Document Databases that don't require installation of some sort?

Comment: db4o is the best solution but isn't free for comercial projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at http://eloquera.com/?
It is free and is a client/server object database.
It is easy to use and fast.
I found it late last year and think it is a great step forward.
Give it a go ,and I don't work for them I just love what their doing.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a bit late but I am using [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) (more [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RavenDBIntro.aspx)) which works like a charm! It works very well with the RavenDB.Client only and a file based document store for simple scenarios.

Comment: It's just commercial (even as a back-end). You have to publish your company's whole code base as open-source to use RavenDB. I have been through that :\

Answer (score 1):

Try [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/). Haven't tried it myself but its an embedded OODB. It has a dual GPL/Commercial license.

Comment: I have looked at using db40 but I am unsure of the GPL license.  I want to use the object database in a web app that I am creating for a small business.  Can I use GPL in that situation?

Comment: You can wrap calls to it in your own library licensed under less restrictive terms. Then call this library from your commercial application.

Comment: Interesting approach but that doesn't really seem worth while or honest.  I will wait until some other open sourcers create something better.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check [STSdb](http://stsdb.com) - its an free open-source embedded object database system (NoSQL key/value pair storage engine) designed for mission critical and real-time applications.

Comment: It's under the GPLv2 for 'free', so bear-in-mind, you'd have to release any derivative code as well. http://stsdb.com/stsdb-w4.0/licensing-pricing/licensing/